# How to make a Facebook-like birthdate picker in SwiftUI?

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

I am trying to make a Facebook-like birthdate picker in SwiftUI that looks like this:

[image]

It doesn't have to look exactly like that, but I want the same style, not the classic Apple-style date picker.

Thank you!